# Angular function syncronization

Tags: angularjs, asynchronous, synchronization, angularjs-service

My question is how to execute 3 functions(declared in service) in order:

```
   function1();
   function2();
   function3();
```

All functions contain http commands(e.g. put or get). that's why if I use code above function 3 will be executed before function 2. I tried to chain functions with then but that didn't help either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return a promise and then use promise chaining, because your functions are async.

```
function1().then(function(response) {
   /* executes function2, if function1 return success */
   function2().then(function(response) {
      /* executes function3, if function2 return success */
      function3();
   }
}
```

In the angular docs (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) you can see how to return a promise. For the case you use the $http or $resource provider: They always return a promise which you can use for your purpose.

Comment: Yes, thanks, is there some other way to do this then using then/promises?

Comment: $http is hardcoded async. You need to write your own provider to make synchronous calls. However this is a really bad idea because your UI is blocking.